# Color item in a datagridview combobox column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a Winform datagridview with a combobox column. Is it possible to color a specific item in the comboboxes? If yes, how can I do this (in C#)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ComboBox1_DrawItem

```
protected void ComboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, 
    System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
{

    float size = 0;
    System.Drawing.Font myFont;
    FontFamily font= null;

    //Color and font based on index//
    Brush brush;
    switch(e.Index)
    {
        case 0:
            size = 10;
            brush = Brushes.Red;
            family = font.GenericSansSerif;
            break;
        case 1:
            size = 20;
            brush = Brushes.Green;
            font = font.GenericMonospace;
            break;
    }

    myFont = new Font(font, size, FontStyle.Bold);
    string text = ((ComboBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString();
    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, myFont, brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
```

Comment: How can I catch the events of the comboboxes in a datagrid view combobox column?

Comment: The documentation for the DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl class has
an example of how you can do exactly what you want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxeditingcontrol.aspx It shows how to connect to the SelectedIndexChanged event on the
combobox that is hosted in the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Handle the [EditingControlShowing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing.aspx) event to perform custom initialization of the editing control when a cell enters [edit mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxeditingcontrol.aspx).

Take a look at [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformsdatacontrols/thread/f31f5677-0709-4469-b65a-f958bbaf8a05) thread.